# rendering with a graphics card

Tags: rendering, gpu

[image]Actually i want to change my render engine .
When using Cycles i want to render on my graphics card (Radeon), but it is shown in OpenCL and not in CUDA as shown in the picture above.

Is it ok to change the settings in the properties panel render tab to GPU compute?
It is taking lot of time, how to reduce the rendering time by my graphics card?

If any mistakes in the question, sorry i'm a beginner, i don't know how to explain my question, thank you.

[image] [image]

Comment: CUDA is only for Nvidia graphics cards. Since your GPU is from AMD, it's in the OpenCL tab. Was that what you were wondering about?

Comment: in rnder tab do i need to change to gpu computing or the cpu for better render

Comment: If you want to use the GPU, then you'll have to set the *Device* to *GPU Compute*. It won't make a difference to the quality of the image (unless you're using volumetrics).

Comment: While you can use "GPU Compute", since you have a GPU, it will use all devices selected under CUDA or OpenCL, means you could select the CPU as well and maybe speed up the rendering. While you only asked for GPU, i believe some users (including me) use not only the GPU. But that is something you can test if it's reasonable for you.

Comment: If you want to use only GPU for rendering you have to increase the tile size to improve the performance. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/render_settings/performance.html#tiles